# Are there any resources or documentation that provide power consumption characteristics of Cooja motes, similar to real hardware

Tags: contiki, contiki-ng

I'm working on a project that involves understanding the power consumption of Cooja motes within Contiki-NG. While I understand Cooja motes are virtual representations, I'm interested in learning about their representative voltage and current values in different operational stages (e.g., idle, transmitting, receiving). Are there any resources or documentation that provide insights into these power consumption characteristics of Cooja motes, similar to how a datasheet would for real hardware

Waiting for the response